# Why are variables set on a page load not available in the document.ready scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have an included javascript file thats initializes an empty array object called "widgets"

```
var Widgets = {};

function Widget(a,b,c){
this.a = a;
...
}
```

in the same include a bunch of function prototypes are defined to add widget info to a widget:

```
Widget.prototype.addWidgetInfo(a,b,c){
 this.info.a = a;
 this.info.b = b;
 ...
}
```

there are also a number of functions that support a document.ready(){ } block in the end of the file.

in the body of the page, for each widget outputted a line of js is outputted as well calling this prototype function

```
Widgets[id] = new Widget();
Widgets[id].addwidgetInfo("bla","bla","bla");
```

When document ready calls however

Widgets[id].info is an empty array....

I can't figure out why on earth this data is not available! please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in the example given.  I'm not sure if they are your problem, or just a problem in your example:

- `addWidgetInfo` isn't being declared correctly. Should be:

  ```
  Widget.prototype.addWidgetInfo = function(a,b,c){
  ```
- `this.info` isn't initialized.  Should be

  ```
  Widget.prototype.addWidgetInfo = function(a,b,c){
      this.info = {};
      this.info.a = a;
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: yeah good point it is my example. i didnt put everything in there =/